# onsen ui not working $http in emulate

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

```
module.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('http://104.155.209.198/list/json')
          .success(function (data) {
              $scope.home_items = data;
              console.log('call HomeController');
          })
          .error(function (error) {
              $scope.error = "error";
          });
      $scope.ClickHome = function (url) {
          $http.get('http://104.155.209.198'+url+'/json')
              .success(function (data) {
                  $scope.list_items = data;
                  console.log($scope.list_items);
                  console.log('call ListItems');
              });
      };
      $scope.ClickList = function (url) {
          $http.get('http://104.155.209.198'+'/list'+url+'/json')
              .success(function (data) {
                  $scope.viewObject = data;
                  console.log($scope.viewObject);
                  console.log('call ViewItems');
              })
      };
  });
```

This is my Angular code. This work in WebBrowers but not working in ios-emulate. what is a problem? not working $http in onsen-ui?

Comment: Do you get any errors if you inspect the page with Safari?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be loading of external content.

You can inspect the problem with Safari. If that's the case, this might help: http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

Add this to `platforms/ios/<appname>/<appname>-Info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

new version of onsen ui not supported $http in emulate android

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    data: 'Username=' + $scope.user.email + '&Password=' + $scope.user.password + '&is_varified='+$scope.user.is_varified+'&gcm_reg_id='+gcm_reg_id,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    url: myService.ajax_base_url+'/login/validate_mobile_user'
}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //console.log(data);
    alert('in success');
    modal.hide();
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    modal.hide();
    alert('in error');
});
```